# how to get a row ID from a Cursor

Tags: android

How do I get the row ID from a Cursor?

Answer (score 14):

I don't think the Cursor exposes this directly.
`SQLiteDatabase.insert()` returns the row id of the newly inserted row. Or in Android the convention is that there is a column named `"_id"` that contains the primary autoincrement key of the table. So `cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))` would retrieve this.

Comment: As Nic mentioned the "_id" is an android convention it does not exist by default.  That is, the table creation is expected to define a column as " _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ", problems such as what CP mentioned in his post if the custom unique _id is not declared.  sqlite creates row ids by default and reserves serveral names {rowid oid _rowid_}.  see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid

Comment: Have to include the "_id" in the string array for query selection.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem where the column index for the primary key was reported as -1 (meaning it isn't there). The problem was that I forgot to include the _ID column in the initial SELECT clause that created the cursor. Once I made sure it was included, the column was accessible just like any of the others.

Answer (score 3):

Concerning the last sentence of Nic Strong's answer,following command didn't work for me. `cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")` was still -1

```
 cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id"))
```

Maybe there's some other issue in my configuration that's causing the problem?

Personally I've taken to maintaining my own custom unique id column in each table I create; A pain, but it gets around this issue.

Comment: Strange, I'm using this exact code: `public static final String ID_NAME = "_id";` `long id = c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DatabaseTable.ID_NAME));` and it's working for me when targeting eclair. (Testing on a Motorola xt720.) Have you moved your cursor to the first valid item with `cursor.moveToFirst()`?

Comment: This happens when you delete rows, I believe.

Comment: As mentioned by Luigi Putanesca, make sure that _ID is in your select clause of query or in projection array

Comment: I found this issue occurred whenever I used the rawQuery method with a "SELECT *"  string (which also contained JOINS). Getting the PK column always returned 0. Using the query method with named columns was fine.

Answer (score 2):

```
return sqlite_db.query(table, new String[] { "rowid", "*" }, where, args, null, null, null);
```

In my case I have "rowid" in DataManager.FIELD_ID and this is SQLite identity column (each table in sqlite has this special kind of column), so I don't need any of my own custom unique id column in tables.

Comment: Can't find `DataManager.FIELD_ID`. I used `"ROWID"` instead. But thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
Cursor cursor = mySQLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { "ROWID", "*" }, where, null, null, null, null);
```

then

```
long rowId = cursor.getLong(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the TABLE is not defined using **`WITHOUT ROWID`** you can get the **ROWID** (or should that be **rowid** see below for case) if you specify it as a column to be retrieved.

For example for a table with 3 defined columns (Names, Colour and Age) with no conventional **_id** column. The following rawQuery works and returns the **ROWID** :-

```
Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("SELECT Names, Colour, Age, ROWID FROM " + TABLE_NAME,null);
```

***Note! that the column name in the cursor is lowercase*** as per :-

[image]

*Note! **ROWID** in the **SELECT SQL** is case independent (e.g. RoWiD works).*

Using

```
Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME,null);
```

**WILL NOT** return the **ROWID** (likewise for null for the columns when using the  `query` method).

Using `query` (*as opposed to `rawQuery`*) works in the same way, that is you need to specifiy ROWID (note alternatives to ROWID below) as a column to be retrieved e.g. :-

```
Cursor csr = db.query(TABLE_NAME,new String[]{
                "OiD",
                "Names",
                "Colour",
                "Age"
        },null,null,null,null,null);
```

---

### Alternatives to ROWID

Instead of **`ROWID`**, you can also use **`_ROWID_`** or **`OID`** (case independent) as the column name in the query noting that the column name in the resultant cursor is **rowid** i.e. **it is lowercase**.