# Why am I having such an error to my code? CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, cursor, indexoutofboundsexception, toast

Is there anyone who can try to find the mistake in my code? I tried many things already but it always ends up with the same error.

This is my code:

```
                String signeedep = spn.getSelectedItem().toString();
                int a = spn1.getSelectedItemPosition();
                Cursor userid = db.getallsigneenumber();

                    userid.moveToPosition(a);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                             userid.getString(1) + "//this is where the error points out
                             was assigned to the " + signeedep + ".",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    userid.close();
                /*
                db.open();
                db.insertAssignsignee(signeedep, userid.getString(0));
                db.close();
                */
                    myMethod();
```

This is my error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main

android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 requested, with a size of 1
```

Comment: What you wanna do exactly calling getString(1) ?

Comment: I want to get the value in column 1 which is the id.

Comment: @Justine does your table contain two column or single column?

Comment: I joined two tables and they have 7 columns altogether.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848056/how-to-get-a-row-id-from-a-cursor

Comment: Thanks but still there's an error. I cant seem to find why yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure your cursor is **not null** and it is having required number of element in it..

remember moveToPosition(1) returns the second row, since it's zero-indexed

Comment: Thanks! I added -1 on my int variable and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should first convert this to a String, using 
    `String userIdString = userid.toString;`
if possible.

Then you can use `userIdString.substring(1,2);`